# what sort of phrase is "as much money as Mick but not as much as Neil"?

Tags: phrases

> Greg makes **as much money as Mick but not as much as Neil.**

is it prepositional phrase, noun phrase ,noun clause,gerund phrase,adverb clause ... ?

**i.e. noun phrase, verb phrase, adverb phrase, adjective phrase, appositive phrase, infinite phrase, participle phrase and gerund phrase.**

why?

Comment: Note that "prepositional" and "noun" are parts of speech. One thing that can confuse people when they analyze sentences is mixing up parts of speech with functions of a chunk of words (technically called a [constituent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_%28linguistics%29)). If possible, try to think of what is it and what it does in the sentence separately.

Comment: not talking about noun and preposition, but noun phrase and prepositional phrase.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the edit! The question is a lot clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

It's a comparative phrase.

A simile is a figure of speech in which a thing is described by being likened to another, usually using as or like, and usually in a phrase or saying.

So it's not a simile, as it's not likening Greg to something or likening his income to anything: it's simply discussing Greg's income comparative to other people's.

"Greg was as rich as Croesus" is a simile.
"Greg was as poor as a church mouse" is a simile.
"Greg's wealth was like a bathful of water - likely to be drained away at any moment" is an extended simile.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a comparative statement.

> Greg makes as much money as Mick but not as much as Neil.

This can be broken down to two separate statements.

1. > Greg makes as much money as Mick

Which means that Greg earns roughly the same amount of money that Mick earns.

2. > Greg doesn't make as much money as Neil does.

Which means that Neil has a higher earning when compared to Greg's income.

These two statements are just combined in the first statement.

Comment: it is not a statement.

Answer (score 0):

This phrase is an example for combined use of two prepositional phrases joined with another conditional clause to make an assumption or to extract a final meaning from those prepositional phrases.